# How can I iterate over a listview in a background thread?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, listview

I've got an application with a ListView and I want to loop through each item in the ListView. But I want to do this in a separate thread.

This is a very simple version of the code - but its error is the same:

```
Private Sub StartToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartToolStripMenuItem.Click
    pingThread = New Thread(AddressOf loopingRoutine)
    pingThread.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub loopingRoutine()
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        MsgBox(item.Text)
    Next
End Sub
```

That causes the following error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ListView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Why is this the case? I've never had this problem before when using DataGridViews.

Can anyone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access WinForms items from a background thread.  They are affinitized to the UI thread.  If you've been able to do this in the past with a different type then you were unlucky that it worked.

Whenever you want to work with a specific controls you need to `Invoke` back to the UI thread to access it's members.  Doing an action such as looping on the members is just not possible on the background thread.

Comment: Many thanks... I intend to go and research multithreading so I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way! Hopefully I can help someone else looking through the net trying to solve this!

You need to call the items and store them as a list using a delegate thread. and then use that... if that makes sense!

Like so:

```
    Private Sub StartToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartToolStripMenuItem.Click
    pingThread = New Thread(AddressOf loopingRoutine)
    pingThread.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub loopingRoutine()
    Dim myList = DirectCast(Invoke(New GetListViewDelegate(AddressOf GetListViewItems)), List(Of String))
    For Each item As String In myList
        Dim array() As String = item.Split(";")
        MsgBox(array(0) & vbCrLf & array(1))
    Next
End Sub

Private Delegate Function GetListViewDelegate() As List(Of String)
Public Function GetListViewItems() As List(Of String)
    Return the list back to the delegate
    Dim pathList = New List(Of String)
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        pathList.Add(item.Text & ";" & item.Index)
    Next
    Return pathList
End Function
```

It may not be the best way to do it - but for a quick and dirty program, it should suffice :)